# Why calling dispatch_sync in current queue not cause deadlock

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, deadlock

the apple document says:(concurrencyProgrammingGuide,page49)
Important: You should never call the dispatch_sync or dispatch_sync_f function from a task that is executing in the same queue that you are planning to pass to the function. This is particularly important for serial queues, which are guaranteed to deadlock, but should also be avoided for concurrent queues.

but the code here not cause a deadlock, since i have ran it many times:

```
    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^(){
    NSLog(@"in outer queue: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^(){
        NSLog(@"do someting thread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    });
});
```

Yet,we all know,in main thread context, if we execute the code below,it will cause deadlock in main thread. so i am confused why calling dispatch_sync in the same thread, one not deadlock(the code above), the other opposite(the code below)?

```
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"________update__UI");
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

`dispatch_get_global_queue()` returns a system-defined global **concurrent** queue.

Comment: And, for completeness, it should be called out that the main thread queue is a **serial** queue.

Answer (score 4):

Serial Dispatch Queue (the main queue and user created queues with default flag) uses only just one thread. Concurrent Dispatch Queue (global queue, created queues with concurrent flag) uses multiple threads (aka thread pool). The number of thread is vary with system, situation.

[image]

Take a look at the following code.

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^(){

    /* Task 1 */

    dispatch_sync(queue, ^(){

        /* Task 2 */

    });
});
```

Task 1 and Task 2 should be executed on the same order as it was queued. Thus, Task 1 is executed, and then Task 2.

On Serial Dispatch Queue, `dispatch_sync` have to wait in order to execute Task 2 on the thread that is executing Task 1 right now. **DEADLOCK**.

On Concurrent Dispatch Queue, `dispatch_sync` usually doesn't need to wait to execute Task 2 on a thread in the thread pool. But the number of thread in the thread pool is not unlimited actually, sometimes `dispatch_sync` have to wait until some other task finished. That's why "**but should also be avoided for concurrent queues**". `dispatch_sync` is also highly optimized, it uses the same thread of Task 1 for Task 2 in some situation.

**EDITED**

Thus, `dispatch_sync` a block means the exactly same as ordinary block(function) call. In this case, DEADLOCK never happened.

**EDITED**

Test code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void task2()
{
    NSLog(@"task2: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
}

void task1(dispatch_queue_t q)
{
    NSLog(@"task1: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    dispatch_sync(q, ^{
        task2();
    });
}

int main()
{
    dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
    dispatch_async(q, ^{
        task1(q);
    });
    dispatch_main();
    return 0;
}
```

lldb log

```
(lldb) breakpoint set -l 6
(lldb) run
task1: <NSThread: 0x1001155a0>{number = 2, name = (null)}
task2: <NSThread: 0x1001155a0>{number = 2, name = (null)}

Process stopped

(lldb) bt
* thread #2: tid = 0x4dbcc, 0x0000000100000d34 a.out`task2 + 4 at a.m:5, queue = 'com.apple.root.default-qos', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100000d34 a.out`task2 + 4 at a.m:5
    frame #1: 0x0000000100000dc5 a.out`__task1_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=<unavailable>) + 21 at a.m:12
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8d6d6c13 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8d6e19a1 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_sync_f_invoke + 39
    frame #4: 0x0000000100000da3 a.out`task1(q=0x00007fff79749b40) + 67 at a.m:11
```

`task1` function calls `task2` function via libdispatch APIs but it almost the same as ordinary function call.

Comment: as you said, on concurrent queue task1 and task2 may be executed by different thread, since there is a thread pool. But, i try to print the [NSThread currentThread] in task1 and task2, it always print the same Thread:         ** ____task1: <NSThread: 0x7fccd2565a50>{number = 2, name = (null)}
 ____task2: <NSThread: 0x7fccd2565a50>{number = 2, name = (null)}**  and shouldn't it cause a deadlock? 1.dispatch_async queue the block then a new thread A will execute the block; 2.the dispatch_sync block thread A 3.since thread A is blocked, task2 will wait forever. but actually it not causes deadlock

Comment: Honestly I don't know any situation that `dispatch_sync` uses a different thread from the current thread on concurrent queue. So `dispatch_sync` might always use the same thread for it I guess. Thus, `dispatch_sync` a block means the exactly same as ordinary block(function) call. no deadlock , indeed.

Comment: Added an evidence of  `dispatch_sync` as ordinary function call.